# Copy current terminal window

Tags: terminal

How do I open terminal in same directory I am in other terminal window?

eg.  have 2 terminals open one in `/tmp` (currently working in this) other `~`, I wish to press magic shortcut to open new terminal window in `/tmp`

Edit: I am on ubuntu running xfce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what terminal program you are using, you have a few options.

If you are using the built in debian/ubuntu/mint (and possibly others) linux terminal, you can press `ctrl+shif+t` to open a new tab in your current directory. It is also possible to run the terminal program like I will describe below, but you can omit the `>/dev/null $`. The command is `gnome-terminal`, which you can set an alias to in your `.bashrc` file, eg `alias nt=gnome-terminal`, which will spawn a new terminal in the current folder every time you run `nt`.

If you are using an different terminal program (I like Terminator, but others include xterm, guake, [etc](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-terminal-emulators/)), You can run that program in your original terminal using `terminator > /dev/null &` which will spawn a background process that starts a new terminal and throws away any output it creates (which shouldn't be anything, but we are just being thorough)